# Reverse order of words in a string

Tags: c++, list, iterator

I am working a problem to reverse the order of words in a string. For example, if you have str1 = "the sky is blue" then the solution should be "blue is sky the".

Here is my code:

```
class Solution 
{
    public:
        list<string> words;

        void createList(string s)
        {
            istringstream iss(s);
            string token;

            while(getline(iss, token, ' '))
            {
                words.push_back(token);
            }
        }

        string reverseWords(string s) 
        {
            list<string>::iterator iter = words.begin();
            string newString = "";

            createList(s);
            newString.append(*iter);
            for (iter = (iter+1); iter != words.end(); iter++)
            {
                newString.append(" ");
                newString.append(*iter);
            }

            return newString;
        }
};
```

My question is.... 
Am I using the list iterator correctly? I got a compiler error that said "Line 25: no match for ‘operator+’ " referring to the for loop in reverseWords().

Comment: I think you need to replace the `iter+1` with `++iter`, but not sure about it

Comment: iterator doesn't have operator+ so iter = (iter+1) gives you the error.

Comment: Or maybe you don't need to increment it at all in the first time. See this reference" http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/list/

Comment: I want the iterator to start just AFTER the first index in the list for the loop. That is why I try (iter+1).

Comment: No need to initialise `newString` before appending to it, btw.

Comment: [`std::list<T>::rbegin()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/rbegin) and [`std::list<T>::rend()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/rend) would likely be handy for this task.

Comment: Could use `std::regex` with `(\\S+)` or `(\\w+)` and reverse the results into a string.. probably not efficient though..

Comment: Honestly, id be inclined to do something more [like this](http://ideone.com/hrayt5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this compiles fine, so yes the ++iter is a valid statement. Incrementing is valid, jumping is not:

```
list<string> words;

void createList(string s)
{
    istringstream iss(s);
    string token;

    while(getline(iss, token, ' '))
    {
        words.push_back(token);
    }
}

string reverseWords(string s) 
{
    list<string>::iterator iter = words.begin();
    string newString = "";

    createList(s);
    newString.append(*iter);
    ++iter;
    for (; iter != words.end(); ++iter)
    {
        newString.append(" ");
        newString.append(*iter);
    }

    return newString;
}
```

Comment: This makes sense, as generally you want an iterator to move forward in single steps. For larger (fixed length) steps, you should not use it, as there is no (or only an expensive) way to check if you did not accidentally iterate right out of the list.

Answer (score 3):

`list` does not support random access iterators, therefore using operator+ with `list` is not allowed, you would use operator++. You have to access the list elements sequentially, just like you'd have to if you were using your own linked list implementation.

You could use a reverse iterator, to reverse your string.

```
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class Solution 
{
    public:
        list<string> words;

        void createList(string& s)
        {
            istringstream iss(s);
            string token;

            while(getline(iss, token, ' '))
            {
                words.push_back(token);
            }
        }

        string reverseWords(string& s) 
        {
            list<string>::reverse_iterator iter = words.rbegin();
            string newString = "";

            createList(s);
            for ( ; iter != words.rend(); ++iter)
            {
                newString.append(" ");
                newString.append(*iter);
            }

            return newString;
        }
};

int main(int, char**)
{
    string in("The sky is always blue");
    Solution s;
    string out = s.reverseWords(in);

    std::cout << in << std::endl;
    std::cout << out << std::endl;
}
```